# Have `zip` utility only echo if a file was added or actually changed

Tags: zip

I'm using `zip` to create an incremental archive.

I would like it to only echo the file if there was a change between source and the archive, or if it's an `added` file.

This would mean if I ran it twice in a row it would echo no files. (easy detection of changes is the point).

Is this possible?

Right now it echoes for every file, even if there has been no change.

I am using this command:

```
zip -r --test "Dest.zip" ./Source
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably want is to [*update* the zip file](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/zip.html):

> update (-u): Update existing entries if newer on the file system and add new files.  If the archive does not exist issue warning then create a new archive.

Therefore, you should try

```
zip -ru "Dest.zip" ./Source
```

Comment: Awesome. I didn't realize "add mode", the default, was adding no matter which version was newer.